# SQL Query join 2 tables group by month

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables 1 named Despesas and other named Receitas, both have the fields
date, and value.
I want to sum the value of both grouping by month and year.
I've tried this

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(DATA) AS m,
    sum(valor) AS p

FROM
    despesas

GROUP BY 
MONTHNAME(DATA)
```

but i've no idea how to join both in one table like this

```
----------------------------------------
-  MONTH - SUM DESPESAS - SUM RECEITAS - 
- JANUARY - 10432.2     -  103.3       -
- MARCH    - 102.2      -   0          -
- APRIL    - 101.2      -    4         -
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drop table if exists t1;
create table t1 (date date, val int);
insert into t1 values ("2015-01-02", 1), ("2015-01-25", 2), ("2015-02-02", 3);
drop table if exists t2;
create table t2 (date date, val int);
insert into t2 values ("2015-01-15", 1), ("2015-02-10", 2), ("2015-03-01", 3);

select monthname(date), sum(val1) DESPESAS, sum(val2) RECEITAS 
   from (
     select date, val1, val2 
        from (select date, val val1, 0 val2 
                 from t1) s1  
              union 
              (select date m, 0 val1, val val2 
                 from t2 ) ) t 
   group by month(date) 
   order by date
```

result

```
monthname(date) DESPESAS    RECEITAS
January         3           1
February        3           2
March           0           3
```

Comment: Can you please explain for what reason `s1` and `t` is?

Comment: @alexander "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: So those are random aliases?

Answer (score 1):

Probably try like below; get the `SUM()` value separately and then you can `JOIN` both tables on the common column `DATA`. See your provided fiddle modified http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd9f9/6

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(d.DATA) AS Month_Name,
    sum(d.valor) AS Despesas_Sum_Valor,
    xx.Receitas_Sum_Valor
FROM
    despesas d JOIN (
SELECT DATA, 
sum(valor) AS Receitas_Sum_Valor
FROM Receitas

GROUP BY MONTHNAME(DATA) ) xx 
ON MONTHNAME(d.DATA) = MONTHNAME(xx.DATA)
GROUP BY 
MONTHNAME(DATA);
```

Comment: @KelvinPrimo, see edit in answer if that helps. Your modified fiddle here as demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd9f9/6